# Google Cloud Vision sample code error (utf-8)

Tags: json, python-3.x, pdf, google-cloud-vision

After following [google cloud vision pdf text detector sample code](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#vision-pdf-detection-gcs-python) I get one issue that after weeks of searching I haven't solved.

```
My code shows an error:
    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/json_format.py", line 397, in Parse
if not isinstance(text, six.text_type): text = text.decode('utf-8')

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

At this point:

```
response = json_format.Parse(
    json_string, vision.types.AnnotateFileResponse())
```

As advised on forums, I ensured the requests module is up to date. Is there anything else you can advise?

P.S I'm doing pdf to text OCR in python3. The google vision link shows my code exactly.

My requirements.txt (the relevant parts):

```
google-cloud-storage==1.11.0
google-resumable-media==0.3.1
google-cloud-core==0.28.1
requests==2.21.0
google-api-core==1.6.0
google-auth==1.6.1
google-cloud-vision==0.35.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.5
```

Comment: You are forcing Python to decode the text as if it's UTF-8. Are you sure it is? (Because the error message says it is not.)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm following google's demo/sample. They could be wrong. If they are, then how would I action the code I need?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you choose an empty destination folder (prefix)?

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714798/i-get-an-json-decode-error-when-using-python-and-google-vision-to-detect-text-on/55908054#55908054